# Does x ^= x & -x; where x is an unsigned integer invoke UB?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Does this function invoke undefined behavior due to the `-` operator being applied to `x` which is `unsigned`?  I searched the standard and couldn't find an explanation.

```
unsigned foo(unsigned x)
{
    return x ^= x & -x;
}
```

IMO yes.

edit

```
void func(unsigned x) 
{
    printf("%x", -x);
}

int main(void)
{
    func(INT_MIN);
}
```

**IMO** The only explanation is that it was promoted to larger signed integer size then converted to unsigned.

If it is promoted to larger integer size, what will happen if there is no larger signed integer type?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224764/discussion-on-question-by-p-j-supports-women-in-poland-does-x-x-x-where).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior of this expression is well defined.

Constructs similar to `x = x + 1` are allowed because `x` isn't assigned a value until all other subexpressions are evaulated.  The same applies in this case.

There is also no problem with `-x` because the expression has unsigned type and thus has well defined wraparound behavior as opposed to overflowing.

Section 6.5.3.3p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the unary `-` operator states:

> The result of the unary `-` operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand.  The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

So since no promotion occurs the type remains `unsigned` throughout the expression.  Though not explicitly stated in the standard, `-x` is effectively the same as `0 - x`.

For the specific case of `INT_MIN` being passed to this function, it has type `int` and is outside of the range of `unsigned`, so it is converted when passed to the function.  This results in the signed value -2,147,483,648 being converted to the unsigned value 2,147,483,648 (which in two's complement happen to have the same representation, i.e. 0x80000000).  Then when `-x` is evaluated, it wraps around resulting in 2,147,483,648.

Comment: I am non convinced 100% especially for the last case in my question. Thank you anyway. BTW it is my personal record `-8`. Still do understand why it was so agresivelly DV-ted.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland There wouldn't be a promotion because `INT_MIN` has type `int`, and passing it to the function results in a conversion to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 9 The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the
> corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the same value in each
> type is the same.<sup>41)</sup> ***A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
> because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
> reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
> represented by the resulting type.***
>
> ---
>
> <sup>41) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as
> arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.</sup>
>
> ...
> **6.3 Conversions**
> ...
> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if
> the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2 ***Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>60)</sup>***
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
> result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>60) The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression</sup>
> ...
> **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**
> ...
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
> equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then ***the operand with
> signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
> integer type.***

In short - the `-x` does not lead to undefined behavior.  The result of the expression is still unsigned, it just maps to a well-defined, non-negative value.