# If an integer is signed by default, why does the signed keyword exist?

Tags: c++, c, unsigned, signed

I'm curious why the signed keyword exists because I believe most integers and other variables are signed by default. Putting the signed keyword before int virtually does nothing. What is it used for, and why does it exist?

Comment: If you have an _unsigned_ value to start, you may wish to _force_ a signed value during calculation (e.g.) `unsigned int x = 0xFFFFFFFF; int y = 7; x = ((signed) x) + y;` There are other [probably better] examples.

Comment: Even when it is a no-op, it's not "doing nothing": it's communicating the programmer's intent.

Comment: @CraigEstey I believe `(signed)` is equivalent to `(int)` ?

Comment: Even more curious is the `auto` keyword. I cannot think of an example where it is necessary in C. (answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23406251/4593267 )

Comment: Note that `auto` does have a use, infers an unspecified type from the variable's usage, in modern C++.

Comment: @chqrlie note that this is tagged as both C and C++, and imho this is a case where that is fine, but `auto` is very different in C and C++

Comment: @EugeneSh. I.A.N.A.L.L but I think that `signed` by itself says convert the base type to signed (e.g. `unsigned int` --> `int` but `unsigned long long` --> `long long`). What' more common is the reverse: `int x; (unsigned) x ...` I _think_ there was a question recently from P__J about UB and signedness that clarified this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899337/does-x-x-x-where-x-is-an-unsigned-integer-invoke-ub

Comment: @CraigEstey: I'm afraid casting an `unsigned long long` as `(signed)` converts it to an `int`, not a `long long`.

Comment: @chqrlie After rereading the link I was referring to, it doesn't seem to cover casting, only unary `-`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are at least two places where the `signed` keyword is not a no-op:

- With `char`: the signedness of "plain" `char` is implementation-defined. On implementations where it's an unsigned type, `signed char` is needed to get the signed variant. Even if `char` is a signed type, `signed char`, `char`, and `unsigned char` are all distinct types.
- With bitfields: bitfield members without explicit signedness have implementation-defined signedness. For example, in

  ```
  struct foo {
      int b:1;
  };
  ```

  the range of values of `b` may be { -1, 0 } or { 0, 1 } depending on the implementation. If you want to be sure you get the signed version, you need the `signed` keyword. Note that while the standard is not very clear on this, on popular implementations, this applies to `typedef` too: if the bitfield member uses a `typedef`-defined type that doesn't include explicit signedness, the implementation-defined signedness (on GCC, set by `-fsigned-bitfields`) applies there too. This means types like `int32_t` should be defined using the `signed` keyword to avoid really bad surprise behavior when they're use in bitfields.

Comment: Re “This means types like int32_t should be defined using the signed keyword to avoid really bad surprise behavior when they're use in bitfields”: Yikes!

Answer (score 4):

`char` is either signed or unsigned, but in any case it is a type distinct from `unsigned char` and `signed char`. Those three are different types:

```
char
signed char
unsigned char
```

If not with `signed` there would be some other way needed to distinguish them.

Even without `char`. Why not? It allows to be explicit:

```
signed int x; // Someone decided that x 
              // must be signed
int y;        // Did the author choose signed 
              // consciously? We cannot tell.
```

Comment: `signed int x;` // Someone copy-pasted the declaration from somewhere and was too scared to remove the magic `signed` keyword

Comment: @anatolyg meh I agree with your point, but there is cargo cult everywhere, thats no reason to try to write code that actually means what it says ;)